# How to Fix "undefined" Methods in the Kinect for Windows v1.8.0 Samples provided in the Developer Toolkit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, kinect, kinect-sdk

I recently got my hands on a kinect for windows, downloaded the SDK 1.8.0, the developer toolkit, and visual studio 2013. I am trying to develop software for the kinect using c#. When exploring the developer toolkit, I noticed that some of the examples they provided would not run properly. The following picture is a screenshot of the Background Removal Sample [image: [1]] that they provide. I clicked install and then opened the project in visual studio and those are the errors that the program picks up. I have not modified the code at all so I am unsure why their sample is wrong. Hopefully I am just missing a downloaded plug in. All help is appreciated as I dont know where else to turn (Microsoft hasn't been any help)

Thanks!!

EDIT: Here's a closeup on the error box[image: Close up on Error Box]

Comment: No one will be clicking on links from unknown user. Paste error messages here.

Comment: Is there a way to post my screenshot not as a link? Cause that does the problem more justice. The error says that initializecomponent isn't defined and a bunch of random stuff like that but I haven't changed the code at all, I've just opened microsofts sample code

Comment: Cut out the error dialog box, or better yet just copy/paste the error into your question.  The image above is too small to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`missing using directive or assembly reference` would be enough. Learn about references for projects in VS, find which one is missing and add it.

Probably you have to fix reference to some sdk library because you have it in another directory than it was present for developer who created the sample.

In solution explorer you have solutions and there are `References` check if there is something with exclamation mark, or search on msdn for class that is causing the issue in which library it is present. Then you can find library in sdk and set correct path to it.

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out when I get home! I went through all the using statements previously and they all seemed to be in order